# Handling <NA> value and replace with ID in R

Tags: r

When i am running my codes, i get CIK number in one row followed by NA.
I wanted to remove the NA and follow it with the respective CIK numbers alongside each Company names.Below is the desired output

Code:

```
base_url <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1409916/000162828017002570/exhibit211nobilishealthcor.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1300317/000119312507128181/dex211.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1453814/000145381417000063/subsidiariesoftheregistran.htm")


df <- lapply(base_url,function(u){

  html_obj <- read_html(u)
  draft_table <- html_nodes(html_obj,'table') 
  cik <- substr(u,start = 41,stop = 47)
  draft1 <- html_table(draft_table,fill = TRUE)
  final <- c(cik,draft1)

})


require(reshape2)
data <- melt(df)
data <- as.data.frame(data,row.names = NULL)
data <- data[,1:2]
names(data) <- c("CIK","Company")

I want the below Ouput:
       CIK              Company
1    1409916           <NA>
2    1409916           ZYX Ltd
3    1409916           Top Gun
4    1409916            ABC Cements
5    1409916             Hyndai Motors    
6    1409916             Zenith
58   1300317            <NA>
59   1300317           Chemical Stores 
60   1300317           Motor Chip     
61   1300317            PWC
62   1300317            Thomson
63   1300317
```

Comment: remove the what? I think you've missed something from your sentence?

Comment: I have made changes in my sentence.I hope you can understand now.

Comment: Do you want to remove all rows that have NA under CIK?

Comment: Can you put the output that you are expecting in the question description?

Comment: I have shown above the desired output i want in the question description

Answer (score 1):

```
data2 <- transform(data, CIK = na.locf(CIK ))
```

Try this code to replace the NA with the previous CIK.

Which will give you:

```
head(data2)
      CIK                                   Company
1 1409916                                      <NA>
2 1409916                                          
3 1409916                                          
4 1409916                        Name of subsidiary
5 1409916       Northstar Healthcare Holdings, Inc.
6 1409916 Northstar Healthcare Acquisitions, L.L.C.
```

Comment: I want to remove the NA and replcae it with the CIK Number.The desired ouput is shown above in the Code.

Comment: Your question isn't asked very well, it's not at all clear what you want. Do you want to use the CIK value from before or after the NA? Why haven't you explained any of this?

Comment: I have shown the output which i want in the description question.I want to show the respecive CIK numbers alongside the Company names.

Comment: Thats not helping.I want the output the way I have shown in the description question. Can you please help me on that ?

Comment: It's not clear how you want to get to the output, the code I have replaced the NA in CIK which is what your question is asking. Why isn't the code here what you want? You need to learn to explain things in more detail.

Comment: I think @Terru_theTerror got to understand what i wanted in my question.

Comment: It's the same output from both codes when I run them?

Comment: The code is the one in the answer above, i.e data2 <- transform(data, CIK = na.locf(CIK ))

Comment: Thank you so much @ManonLyn 9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CIK<-as.character(data$CIK)

for (i in 1:length(CIK))
{
  ifelse(is.na(CIK[i]),CIK[i]<-val,val<-CIK[i])
}
```

It works if in the first position of CIK you have an ID.

```
data$CIK<-CIK
head(data)
      CIK                                   Company
1 1409916                                      <NA>
2 1409916                                          
3 1409916                                          
4 1409916                        Name of subsidiary
5 1409916       Northstar Healthcare Holdings, Inc.
6 1409916 Northstar Healthcare Acquisitions, L.L.C.
```

Now you can clean the data.frame from empty rows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I got the output.Can you please explain me a bit about your code.What exactly have you done?

Comment: Inside the for loop, the code iterates over each element of CIK, if it's not equal to NA (so it's a valid ID) the value is stored in "val", if it's equal to NA the value is replaced using "val" (last ID seen).

Comment: Yes.I understood now. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Hi @ Terru_theTerror, can you pls share your email or facebook? I need some more help in R programming for different scenario.                                     Thanks Gautam

Comment: You can find me on twitter: @dawydeb

Comment: Thanks :) I will contact you.